# Primefaces blockUi trigger by boolean value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to trigger primefaces `<p:blockUI>` using boolean in backing bean? In this [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml), it requires a commandButton to trigger the the blockUI. What I want is block some part of the page base on a boolean in the backing bean. Is this possible? I tried setting the rendered attribute in the `<p:blockUI>` tag but it still won't work.

Here is my code:

```
<p:blockUI block="grid" rendered="#{bean.trueValue}"></p:blockUI>

<p:panelGrid id="grid">
  -- content
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call hide() and show() method of BlockUI from Managed Bean.
You can do that by using RequestContext:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("widgetVar.show()");
```

Another is you can pass the variable to JavaScript function and then let the Javascript function take care of that for you.

```
onClick="func(#{elvariable})"

<script type="text/javascript">
function func(value)
{
if(value==something){
widgetVar.show();
}else{
widgetVar.hide();
}
}
```

Comment: I need to trigger the blockUI after page load not by a button click